# Help ordering Post loop by two meta values

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, order, sort, pre-get-posts

Background:
I have a custom post type "events" which has a post meta value of a unix timestamp called event start date. I also have a post meta value of ticket_status that has 3 possible values (S=Sold Out, Y=On Sale, I=Invite Only). I currently have it sorting by the event start date from earliest to latest.

Issue:
I want the events to display from earliest to latest as I have them now, but I want all sold out events to appear at the bottom of the list.

I currently have this as my $args as:

```
'post_type' => array('events'),
'posts_per_page' => 25,
'post_status'     => 'publish',
'meta_key' => "event_start_date",
'orderby' => "meta_value title',
'order' => 'ASC'
```

I also have a filter which is returning $orderby:

```
$orderby .= ", wp_postmeta.meta_value " . $query->query_vars['order'];
```

I have tried ordering by event_start_date then by ticket_status, but then it orders them by 1)On sale events, 2)invite events and then 3)sold out events. This results in the events showing in the wrong chronological order.

Is it possible to do a case statement? Similar to this:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ticket_status = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, event_start_date ASC
```

Anything that can help me do this would be awesome! Thank you in advance.

Comment: One option would use `wp_rewind_posts()`.  Run your query once, looping through to display Y & I values, sorted by date.  Rewind and loop again on the same query result, displaying S values at the bottom.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts

Comment: You can get the posts by start date with get_posts which return an array of WP_Post Objects and the filter the array with some criteria ie move the sold out events to another array. Then you can run a for each loop and display your events. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Ok thanks for your comments. There is no way within the wordpress query structure to do this right? I would have to just write a custom sql query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Wordpress 4.2 or newer then you can do the following:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type'       => 'events',
    'posts_per_page'  => 10,
    'meta_query'      => array(
        'relation'    => 'AND',
        'start_date_clause' => array(
            'key'     => 'start_date',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'ticket_status_order_clause' => array(
            'key'     => 'ticket_status_order',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'order_by' => array(
        'start_date_clause' => 'ASC',
        'ticket_status_order_clause' => 'ASC',
    )
);
```

You have to create a ticket_status_order because there's no way to order by string from your available keys/values:

ASC: (I=Invite Only, S=Sold Out, Y=On Sale)
DESC: (Y=On Sale, S=Sold Out, I=Invite Only)

"Sold Out" always sit in the middle.

For more information about the query, take a look here:
[Query improvements in WP 4.2: ‘orderby’ and ‘meta_query’](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/)